Как вырезать url в тексте PHP
нужно из большого текста вырезать с помощью preg_match_all ссылки если они есть, но я вообще не понимаю как создавать регулярные выражения, не подскажите как их можно сделать?
Пример:
Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem https://my.site.ru/123/sdsd/21321/sdf/df 
Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem http://my.site.ru/123/sdsd/21321/sdf/df  
Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem 


Попробовать так:
$text = <<<TEXT
Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem https://my.site.ru/123/sdsdjj/21321/sdf/df ыва ыва 
Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem http://my.site.ru/123/sdsdkk/21321/sdf/df test ewtwtr
Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem https://google.com Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem 
TEXT;


preg_match_all("/((http|https)?:\/\/(\S+))/",
    $text,
    $out);
    
print_r($out[0]);


Спасибо большое, а можно сделать тоже самое для DOI или это нужно использовать другой инструмент?
11.111/1111-111A.11.1.11 или 44.44444/aaaaa.4444444444

Думаю можно, но надо знать критерии для "вырезания".  Т.е. из чего состоит doi
